# Copy the newest file from all the subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am trying to get all the newest file from subdirectories into one network directory with a command without getting the subdirectory structures. They are the SQL Server log files with extension of `*.trn`. I have the following but it doesn't work.

Trying to get only the newest `*.trn` files from ...........Backup and it's subdirectories.

```
for /R E:\SQLSERVER\PRODINSTANCE1\Backup %%f in (*.trn) do xcopy %%f "\\198.152.71.14\NetBackups$\MSSQL\Logs" /B /O:D /d /Y
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dir`  command with the `/od` switch and a `for` loop:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d /r "E:\SQLSERVER\PRODINSTANCE1\Backup" %%a in (*) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "%%~a"') do set "newest=%%~fi"
    xcopy "!newest!" "\\198.152.71.14\NetBackups$\MSSQL\Logs" /B /O:D /d /Y
)
```

For more help enter `help dir` in the command prompt.

Comment: I wasn't sure @Calvin only wanted the _one_ newest file or _all_ the newest/updated files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using xcopy correctly. `/O` doesn't take arguments. It only copies ownership/ACL info. (Is that really what you want for log files?)

Since you didn't describe what "doesn't work" means, my only suggestion is to hedge against file names with spaces in them.

```
FOR /R "%SRC_DIR%" %%f in (*.trn) do xcopy "%%~f" "%DEST_DIR%" /B /O /D /Y
```

This worked for me (I tested with .pdf's).